# Pandas cycling through a period of 28 days using timestamp (e.g.)

Tags: pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to work out how I could get a cycle of 28 days in my df. What I mean is that I have dataset spanning more than a couple of years with full dates. There doesn't seem to be a stfrtime that looks at a 28 day (lunar month).

How can I have the minimum date be 1 (say for 1st of January 2018) and 28 for (28th of January 2018)
The 29th of January again becomes 1 and 30th of January 2 and so on ...

How can I achieve this cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that:

Input data (the worst case):

```
        Date
         Date
0  2018-07-12
1  2018-07-13
2  2018-07-14
3  2018-07-14  # <- duplicate day
4  2018-07-15
5  2018-07-30  # <- missing days
6  2018-07-31
7  2018-08-08  # <- end cycle day, missing days
8  2018-08-08  # <- duplicate day
9  2018-08-09  # <- new cycle day
10 2018-08-10
```

Use `np.tile` to repeat the period:

```
df['Day'] = (df['Date'].dt.day_of_year - df['Date'].min().day_of_year) % 28 + 1
```

Result output:

```
>>> df
         Date  Day
0  2018-07-12    1
1  2018-07-13    2
2  2018-07-14    3
3  2018-07-14    3
4  2018-07-15    4
5  2018-07-30   19
6  2018-07-31   20
7  2018-08-08   28
8  2018-08-08   28
9  2018-08-09    1
10 2018-08-10    2
```

Comment: I actually have multiple occurences of a single date. Is there anything that could work on df['date']  which is a timestamp ?

Comment: And do you have hole in your series?

Comment: The first date is day 1 even if the min is 2018-08-27?

Comment: @DharmenderTathgur. Can you check if it fit your need?